# Deploy:symlink on capistrano points the "current" directory to previous release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, symlink

I am using capistrano to deploy my Ruby on Rails project. I am on a Dreamhost VPS and since a few weeks ago, with no change in capistrano or passenger, I began to experience a strange problem with the deployment:

Every time capistrano is deploying my application, everything goes right except deploy:symlink (which is called by default) that should point the "current" directory to the newest release. Although the new release is deployed properly to the "releases" directory, the problem is the "current" symlink is always set to previous release instead of the new one. So I can deploy apps but I always have to run the deploy two times in a row.

You can see the capistrano log here: 
http://img715.imageshack.us/img715/7803/capistranoproblemb.png

Has anybody else experienced this before or can help me solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this with an additional deploy task that recreates the symlink using a different internal variable name with the correct path to the latest release (release_path instead of latest_path or something like that).

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Recreate symlink"
  task :resymlink, :roles => :app do
    run "rm -f #{current_path} && ln -s #{release_path} #{current_path}"
  end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:resymlink", "deploy:update_crontab"
```

Comment: In the latest Capistrano, it's `deploy:create_symlink` instead of `deploy:symlink`.

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to the one given by @knocte. The kludge above may work, but it's a code smell.

Comment: @JellicleCat: what version of capistrano are you using?

Comment: @knocte : I don't have access to the workstation in question anymore, but I guess that it was v2.X.

Answer (score 6):

I think @foresth's answer is not a good solution.

I think what happens is that you're experiencing [this horrible bug](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/440) of capistrano.

The way to work-around the bug is the following: **DO NOT READ THE `latest_release` VARIABLE BEFORE THE TASK `deploy` HAPPENS**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Adjusting my custom tasks according to this bug resolved the issue.

Comment: @brendan: what version of capistrano did you reproduce the bug with? they are asking me that in the github issue I linked...

Comment: Looks like it was 2.15.4 @knocte

Comment: @brendan: thanks, and can you reproduce it with 3.x?

Comment: I'm encountering this issue randomly with 3.x, but I'm not using the latest_release variable at all. foresth's answer may be a code smell, but it's the only way I can currently ensure that my symlinks are correct on every deployment.

Comment: @JoseRafaelSantiagoJr: yeah, I guess my answer applied more to the version 2.x of capistrano, back in the day