# Capistrano Symfony current symlink not working

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, symlink

I'm deploying a Symfony application and i've got a problem with the symlink on current directory.

It's works when i delete the symlink and i deploy again, it's the update with the symlink which fail!!!

I have tested those solutions:

[Deploy:symlink on capistrano points the "current" directory to previous release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141454/deploysymlink-on-capistrano-points-the-current-directory-to-previous-release)

But it doesnt work, there is my deploy files :

```
set :application, 'aci'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/repo.git'

set :scm, :git

set :composer_install_flags, '--no-interaction --optimize-autoloader'

# Symfony console commands will use this environment for execution
set :symfony_env,  "prod"

# Set this to 2 for the old directory structure
set :symfony_directory_structure, 3
# Set this to 4 if using the older SensioDistributionBundle
set :sensio_distribution_version, 5

# symfony-standard edition directories
set :app_path, "app"
set :web_path, "web"
set :var_path, "var"
set :bin_path, "app"

# The next 3 settings are lazily evaluated from the above values, so take care
# when modifying them
set :app_config_path, "app/config"
set :log_path, "app/logs"
set :cache_path, "app/cache"

set :symfony_console_path, "app/console"
set :symfony_console_flags, "--no-debug"

# Remove app_dev.php during deployment, other files in web/ can be specified here
set :controllers_to_clear, ["app_*.php"]

# asset management
set :assets_install_path, "web"
set :assets_install_flags,  '--symlink'

# Share files/directories between releases
set :linked_files, []
set :linked_dirs, ["app/logs"]

# Set correct permissions between releases, this is turned off by default
set :file_permissions_paths, ["app"]
set :permission_method, false

# Share files/directories between releases
set :linked_files, %w{app/config/parameters.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{app/logs web/uploads}

after 'deploy:starting', 'composer:install_executable'
after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:assets:install'
after 'deploy', 'deploy:symlink:release'
```

Comment: ` it doesnt work` any error text, log or any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution

In it wasn't an symlink problem, but an APC problem so there 2 solutions :

First > speed and dirty :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Second > long and more clear :

- Install https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle
- Add this on your .rake :

  namespace :symfony do
    desc "Clear apc cache"
    task :clear_apc do
       on roles(:app) do
              symfony_console "apc:clear"
       end
    end
  end

Add this on your deploy.rb

```
after "deploy", "symfony:clear_apc"
```

So now you clear your apc cache after each deploy and your project is up to date.